# How can i Insert into one table and Update another table using Linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following linq expression, I am trying to create a new record in to address table and Update customer table with the newly created AdressID, How can i create a new address get the new AddressID and update customer table

```
 if (request == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
            if (request.AddressToCreate == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request.AddressToCreate));     

            var address = Mapper.Map<Address>(request.AddressToCreate);
            address.CreatedBy = request.AddressToCreate.CreatedBy;
            address.CreatedDate = SystemClock.UtcNow;
            address.UpdatedBy = request.AddressToCreate.UpdatedBy;
            address.UpdatedDate = SystemClock.UtcNow;

              await Context.AddAsync(address);

            var rps = Context.Customers .Where(rc => rc.ID == request.ID).SingleOrDefault();
                    rps.AddressID = request.AddressToCreate.ID;

            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But `request.AddressToCreate.ID;` returns 0, How can i modify my code to get the New AddressID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this:
Firstly you may not have an Id property to your AddressToCreate.
Secondly AddAsync() may not call Context.SaveChangesAsync() so the entity is not commited to database and the id is 0.

Try it like this;

```
  await Context.AddAsync(address);
  await Context.SaveChangesAsync(); // this is optional only if you have modified AddAsync() and it doesnt call SaveChangesAsync inside
var rps = Context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(rc => rc.ID == request.ID);
  rps.AddressID = address.ID;
  await Context.UpdateAsync(rps);

  await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```